# Variable should be declared

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using  T-SQL. The goal is to insert multiples files into a database.
If I'm using without a loop, it's working fine.

In the loop, I always get this error:

> @InputXML should be declared

My code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP_FILES') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_FILES

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_FILES
(
    FileName VARCHAR(MAX),
    DEPTH VARCHAR(MAX),
    [FILE] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
 
INSERT INTO #TEMP_FILES
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\MyServer\MyFolder\',1,1
    
DELETE FROM #TEMP_FILES WHERE RIGHT(FileName,4) != '.XML'
    
--
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
    
TRUNCATE Table MyTable2

DECLARE @InputXML XML
DECLARE @FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX),@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_FILES)
BEGIN
    SET @FILENAME = (SELECT TOP 1 FileName FROM #TEMP_FILES)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT @InputXML = CAST(x AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK \\MyServer\MyFolder\'''+ @FILENAME +''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
       
    INSERT INTO MyTable2 ([id],[version], [name], [listId], [listCode])
        SELECT 
            product.value(''(@id)[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(10)''), 
            product.value(''(@version)[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(14)''), 
            product.value(''(name[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(255)''),
            product.value(''(listId[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(9)''),
            product.value(''(listCode[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(10)'')
        FROM @InputXML.nodes(''xxx/values/value'') AS X(product)'

    EXEC(@SQL)
    
    DELETE FROM #TEMP_FILES 
    WHERE FileName = @FILENAME
END
```

Comment: Variables declared outside of a dynamic statement have no context inside it. Either declare them inside the statement (which you should be doing here), or pass them as parameters in your call to `sys.sp_executesql` (you can't parametrise `EXEC (@SQL)`, and why you shouldn't be using it)

Comment: Also `'...\\MyServer\MyFolder\'''+ @FILENAME +'''...'` is wide open to injection. If you are injected a value, make sure you properly escape the values.

Comment: @Larnu Am I correct in saying `QUOTENAME(@filename, '''')` should work?

Comment: The *entire* value needs to be quoted, @Charlieface , not the last part of the file name: [BULK *'data_file'*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#bulk-data_file). Note, as well, that `QUOTENAME`'s first parameter's data type is a `sysname`, so will truncate values longer than 128 characters (which file paths can be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the variable inside the dynamic SQL (which should be `nvarchar` not `varchar`). You should also use `QUOTENAME` to ensure no issues with the filename:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
DECLARE @InputXML XML;
SELECT @InputXML = CAST(x AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + QUOTENAME(N'\\MyServer\MyFolder\' + @FILENAME, '''') + N', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
       
INSERT INTO MyTable2 ([id],[version], [name], [listId], [listCode])
    SELECT 
    product.value(''(@id)[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(10)''), 
    product.value(''(@version)[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(14)''), 
    product.value(''(name[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(255)''),
    product.value(''(listId[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(9)''),
    product.value(''(listCode[1])'', ''NVARCHAR(10)'')
   
    FROM @InputXML.nodes(''xxx/values/value'') AS X(product)'
```

I will say though, that I urge you to find another method to load files into SQL Server. Dynamic `OPENROWSET`, especially from user input, is not advisable. Bulk Insert or BCP may be an option.

Comment: Though I note this under the questio, just to reiterate that `QUOTENAME(N'\\MyServer\MyFolder\' + @FILENAME, '''')` would truncate long filepaths. the first parameter of `QUOTENAME` is a `sysname` (a synonym of `nvarchar(128)`). If you want could have values longer, then you'll need to use `REPLACE`, or a udf (such as I demonstrate [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/an-in-depth-look-at-injecting/#quotefunctions)).

Comment: @Larnu Before I would mess around with that I would just use proper client code to do this, such as bcp. T-SQL is horrible for dealing with files

Comment: I should insert at least 10 huge XML file. But i don't know how to do it with bcp.

Comment: I don't disagree on that, @Charlieface , just pointing out that `QUOTENAME` is specifically designed for quoting object names, not file paths, so using it for values that *could* be longer than 128 characters can result in truncation.